# Windows Service Name through PID

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have an application that needs to stop a service and, if this service does not stop, run a KillTask. Currently, I can return the process path and its PID, but I cannot return the Service Name through the PID to send a "ServiceStop".

Is it possible to return the Service Name using a PID? If not, is it then possible to stop a service using the PID?

My current function to stop the service by the Service Name:

```
function ServiceStop(sMachine, sService: String) : Boolean;
var
  schm,
  schs: SC_Handle;
  ss: TServiceStatus;
  dwChkP: DWord;
begin
  schm := OpenSCManager(PChar(sMachine), nil, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
  if (schm>0) then
  begin
    schs := OpenService(schm, PChar(sService), SERVICE_STOP or
      SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
    if (schs>0) then
    begin
      if (ControlService(schs, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, ss)) then
        if (QueryServiceStatus(schs, ss)) then
          while (SERVICE_STOPPED<>ss.dwCurrentState) do
          begin
            dwChkP := ss.dwCheckPoint;
            Sleep(ss.dwWaitHint);
            if (not QueryServiceStatus(schs, ss)) then
              Break;
            if (ss.dwCheckPoint < dwChkP) then
              Break;
          end;
      CloseServiceHandle(schs);
    end;
    CloseServiceHandle(schm);
  end;
  Result := SERVICE_STOPPED=ss.dwCurrentState;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can enumerate all services using [EnumServicesStatusEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-enumservicesstatusexa) with `SC_ENUM_PROCESS_INFO`.

The [SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-service_status_process) contains `DWORD dwProcessId;`; just look for yours.

Comment: +1: Obligatory warning to the OP though: keep in mind that a single process can host multiple Windows Services (prime example, Windows' own svchost.exe instances). Thus, know what you are doing when you kill be PID, you might reap more than you inteded.